# The lambda invariant 

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, riemann-surfaces, modular-forms, hyperbolic-geometry

Consider the strip $\{x+iy: -1\leq x < 1 , y>1/2\}$ in the complex upper half plane and let $\lambda$ be the usual $\Gamma(2)$-invariant modular function on the complex upper-half plane.

**Question.** Can one show that the unit circle lies in $$\lambda(\{x+iy: -1\leq x < 1 , y>1/2\})?$$

Comment: You wrote $1\leq x <1$. I'm sure that's not what you meant.

Comment: There are still some $1$s that should be $-1$s.